Whatsapp API | Sending template text with status 200 but never deliver
I trying to send a message with text template and the API returns me a 200 status but i never receive the message, with hello_world template ocurrs the same and if i send plain text message(if i write first) works fine.
(https://i.sstatic.net/BHqfPuTz.png)(https://i.sstatic.net/kEiBhpeb.png)

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Check for the callbacks. Issues like pricing / re-engagement / recipient's client compatibility  are notified via callbacks.
